# Spring Boot Maven plugin could not be resolved

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-3

I'm new to the backe-end development and when I'm initializing my very first project on Spring Boot 3 using IntelliJ IDEA, I got these two errors:

**Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.27 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:jar:1.9.3, org.graalvm.compiler:compiler:jar:22.3.3, org.graalvm.compiler:compiler:jar:22.3.3, org.graalvm.compiler:compiler:jar:22.3.3, org.graalvm.compiler:compiler:jar:22.3.3: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:jar:1.9.3 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:jar:1.9.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Read timed out**

**Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.4' not found**

I've searched and tried setting --> Build,Execution,Deployment-->Build Tools-->Maven and click the "Use plugin registry" and File--> Invalide Caches--> Restart but the IDEA still throws these two errors. I don't know how to solve this, please give me advice if you know how to deal with it, thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure: did you have access to the internet when you initialized your project? Could you try and reproduce using https://start.spring.io from your browser and then command line or IDE?

Comment: @AnthonyDahanne Hi, I've tried to recreate the project and find that the downloading of spring boot maven plugin is a little bit slow on my machine, when it is successfully downloaded, the error disappeared, thank you so much for your reply!